# How to execute all scripts in a path?

Tags: bash, scripts

Suppose I have a script that receives a path as a parameter. How could I execute all the scripts located in that path?

Answer (score 16):

Assuming by path you meant path to a directory, use `run-parts`. From `man run-parts`:

```
run-parts - run scripts or programs in a directory
```

At first you need to set execute permission on all the scripts you want to run. Normally `run-parts` will ignore the directories and also the files that are not executable resides in that directory.

Although before running you should check which files will be run by the `--test` option:

```
run-parts --test /path/to/directory
```

I should mention that `run-parts` has a strict naming convention for the scripts to be executed:

```
If neither the --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given 
then the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and
lower-case letters, ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens.
```

Check `man run-parts` to get more idea.

Comment: Reading a little bit, I found this:
#!/bin/bash
scripts_to_run_dir=/home/you/Dropbox/scripts_to_run
for script in "$scripts_to_run_dir"/*
do
    if test -x "$script"; then
        "$script"
    fi
done

It worked for me, what do you think?

Comment: @LautaroAlvarez What you are doing with that script, could be easily done with a simple command `run-parts /home/you/Dropbox/scripts_to_run` ..be careful about the naming though..

Comment: run-parts is cool. But it made for cron.d and write to syslog as cron.notice. But it good source of ideas, like skip temp and backup files...

Answer (score 10):

Run-parts will work if your scripts have the correct names. If you don't want to deal with renaming your scripts to fit `run-parts`'s complex naming scheme, you could do something as simple as

```
for file in ~/target/*; do $file 2>/dev/null; done
```

That will attempt to execute all files (and directories) found in `~/target`. The `2>/dev/null` redirects error messages so it won't complain when attempting to run directories or non executable files.

Alternatively, you can try the more sophisticated

```
for file in ~/target/*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] && [ -x "$file" ] && "$file"
done
```

This will check whether each of the results is a file (`[ -f $file ]`), is executable (`[ -x $file ]`) and only if both those tests are successful will it attempt to execute the file.

Comment: This one worked perfectly for me in a project (a forked repo) I'm working on - https://github.com/rattfieldnz/Vaprobash/blob/master/setup_projects.sh.